# Firebase .on('value') code block not executing inside cloud function. Any suggestions to fix?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am finding it really strange that the same piece of code it executing when I place it in a .html and check the console logs all looks fine, but when I'm placing exactly same code block inside a cloud function that does not execute and is being skipped over for some reason. All I need to do is fetch some config parameters from a config object and use them as needed.

```
  var db = admin.database().ref();
  var configRef = db.child("config");

  configRef.on('value', function(snap){
    var snapvalue = snap.val();
    var totalLength = Object.keys(snapvalue).length;
      $.each( snapvalue, function( key, value ) {
        console.log(value,key);
    });
  });
```

Completed cloud function looks like this:

```
exports.myFunction = functions.database.ref('/object/{list}').onWrite(event =>{

    console.log("Inside myFunction...");

    var db = admin.database().ref();
    var configRef = db.child("config");

    configRef.on('value', function(snap){
      var snapvalue = snap.val();
      $.each( snapvalue, function( key, value ) {
          console.log(value,key);
      });
    });

    console.log("Leaving myFunction...");

})
```

I am getting the console logs before and after `on('value')` block so function is executing but not the `on('value')` code block.

Comment: Would you care to share the entire function that you deployed?  How are you triggering it?

Comment: Cloud function is executing..l all code before and after the on('value') code block is executing fine.. so I don't think deployment is an issue.. but perhaps I am missing something or not doing it right... here is complete function...

``

Comment: Could you please show the entire function?

Comment: `exports.myFunction = functions.database.ref('/object/{list}').onWrite(event =>{
    var db = admin.database().ref();
    var configRef = db.child("config");
    configRef.on('value', function(snap){
      var snapvalue = snap.val();
      $.each( snapvalue, function( key, value ) {
          console.log(value,key);
      });
    });
  })`

Comment: Above code is trimmed down version of a very large function... as there are limits to comment size and also most of other code would be irrelevant so I did not paste the complete function here.

Comment: I have updated the question above with more details.

Comment: @Doug, Do you see a possible reason why this code block should not execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Cloud Functions, you need to [return a promise](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) (note the comments in the code samples) that resolves when all of the asynchronous work is done in the function.  once() executes asynchronously and returns a promise, so you should return its promise so Cloud Functions knows when it's time to clean up.

Also, it's probably easier to use then() to continue your work when the data is available.

```
exports.myFunction = functions.database.ref('/object/{list}').onWrite(event => {

    console.log("Inside myFunction...");

    var db = admin.database().ref();
    var configRef = db.child("config");

    return configRef.once('value').then(snap => {
        var snapvalue = snap.val();
        $.each(snapvalue, function( key, value ) {
            console.log(value,key);
        });
    });
})
```

If you're going to work with Cloud Functions, you will really have to also learn about how to use promises.

Comment: It should be once() to do a single query.  You can't listen indefinitely with Cloud Functions.

Comment: Thanks, Doug! It worked. At least, it went insde the code block. However, bit curious, could we do it using .on? Also.. I got the following error with above code: `ReferenceError: $ is not defined at configRef.once.then.snap'

Comment: Ok, got you! That clarification makes sense.